# Eclipse CDT conditional breakpoint not working when checking for double expressions

Tags: c++, eclipse, conditional-statements, breakpoints

I'm using Eclipse CDT 4.4.1 (Luna). When It comes to setting a conditional breakpoint, it seems that Eclipse can't deal with float/double expressions. Everything goes fine when, for example, I test for an expression like "t > 1", but when I try to check if "t > 1.55", Eclipse dumps the followig error: "Breakpoint installation failed: Number 1.55 is invalid".

Furthermore, when using the "ignore count" feature, I get different results different times, always resulting in Eclipse jumping over the breakpoint more times than I have set in the breakpoint properties.

Anyone knows the reason for this behavior?

Thanks in advance.